# HTCLIENT in a popup window causes the cursor to bug

Tags: c, winapi

Below is a `WS_POPUP` window, it's procedure always returns `HTCLIENT` on `WM_NCHITTEST`. The cursor turns into the waiting one (the blue disk) whenever it enters the window. This doesn't happens when I return `HTNOWHERE` for exemple.

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_NCHITTEST: return HTCLIENT;
        default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wp, lp);
    }
}

int main(void){
    WNDCLASSEX wcx = {};
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wcx.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    wcx.lpszClassName = L"Win32Class";
    RegisterClassEx(&wcx);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, wcx.lpszClassName, L"Title",
    WS_POPUP, 150, 150, 512, 256, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, 1);

    MSG msg; while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi linternetsansfil, has this issue been solved?

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting a class cursor when you register your window class, and you're not handling `WM_SETCURSOR` either. The docs explain why this is a problem:

**WNDCLASSEX.hCursor**:

*A handle to the class cursor. This member must be a handle to a cursor resource. **If this member is NULL, an application must explicitly set the cursor shape** whenever the mouse moves into the application's window.*

**WM_SETCURSOR**:

*The DefWindowProc function also uses this message to set the cursor to an arrow if it is not in the client area, or to the **registered class cursor if it is in the client area**.*